# RXJS Map and FlatMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am a newbie in angular 2 and RXJS Observables, I am doing one thing since morning, its done but I am not able to get how it is working.

Here is my test.json file under `Assests/api` folder:

```
[ {
    "name" :"James T",
    "address": {
          "Street" : {
              "data": ["Austin","I","J"]
            },
          "District":"XYZ",
          "test" : {
              "insideTest":"insideTest1"
          }

    }
},
{
    "name" :"James T 2",
    "address": {
        "Street" : {
            "data": ["Austin2","I2","J2"]
          },
          "District":"XYZ 2",
          "test" : {
              "insideTest":"insideTest2"
          }

    }
},
{
    "name" :"James T 3",
    "address": {
        "Street" : {
            "data": ["Austin3","I3","J3"]
          },
          "District":"XYZ 3",
          "test" : {
              "insideTest":"insideTest3"
          }

    }
}

]
```

Then I have a service that expose this api named `questionService.ts`, Here is the code of that:

```
getTheJsonFile(): Observable<any[]>{
        return  this._http.get('assets/api/test.json')
        .map(response=>{
            return response.json();
        });
      }
```

And finally in my component I am calling this service as:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Campaign} from '../models/campaign';
import {Questions} from '../models/questions';
import {QuestionService} from '../question/question.service';
import { Http , Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import "rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-campaign',
      templateUrl: './campaign.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['../custom.css'],
      providers: [QuestionService]
    })
    export class CampaignComponent implements OnInit {


      questionTypes: any;
      questions: Questions[];

     public campaign: Campaign;
      constructor(public questionService : QuestionService,private _http: Http) { 

      }


      ngOnInit() {
       this.getTheJson()
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log("And the data is--->"+data["address"]["Street"]["data"]);
          data["address"]["Street"]["data"].forEach(test=>console.log("Test Data-->"+test)) 

        });
      }

    getTheJson(): Observable<any>{
     return  this.questionService.getTheJsonFile()
      //.map(element => element)
      //.do(x => console.log("Mydata--->"+JSON.stringify(x)))
      .flatMap(element => element)
    }
   }
```

Now my question is if I am removing `flatMap(element => element)` from getTheJson() method, it is returning null/undefined, why this is happening?
And again If I am calling map() instead of flatMap() then also it is returning the Undefined result.

While on other side I have the another method that works exactly same but for that I do not need to call flatMap(). Please help!

Comment: 1. what do you actually want to achieve? 2. does your service return actual json as a whole?

Comment: Your commented-out `map` call does nothing; it returns the value unmodified and that value is an array. Using `flatMap` sees individual array elements emitted instead of the array. That is, the array is flattened into the stream. The logging in your `subscribe` expects a stream of elements - not an array - so it only works with the `flatMap` call. BTW, `flatMap` is an alias for `mergeMap`.

Comment: @cartant didn't know `flatMap === mergeMap`. Thanks!

Comment: @BeetleJuice this issue was just opened: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3006

Comment: There are a tone of resources of there related to map vs flatMap. Down voted for lack of research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your decoded json is an array of objects. `flatMap` will basically transform it into an observable that emits one object at a time:

```
object...object...object...
```

After removing the `flatMap`, what you get from subscribe becomes just one value:

```
[object, object, object]
```

So you would have to adjust accordingly because this code fails:

```
subscribe(data => {
          // data["address"] is undefined because you're getting an array of objects
          data["address"]["Street"]["data"].forEach(test=>console.log("Test Data-->"+test)) 

    })
```

So after removing `flapMap`, you could do something like this:

```
subscribe(data => {
    data.forEach(person => {
        console.log(`name: ${person.name}`,`street: ${person.address.street.data}`);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me.